# Which android.widget class is equivalent to <a href..>?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am looking for the *android.widget* class that would be equivalent to the `<a href=..>` html tag.
I have looked into the [official documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) for the android.widget package but I just can't find what I am looking for.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit lost, what do you try to do?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: a very simple link, I just don't want to use a button! Is it even possible?

Comment: Ok that's what I wanted to know. As the reason why I want to use a "link" style instead of a button, it is actually for a login page. At the bottom of the page I will just have: "Don't have an account yet? Register". The "register" would be the link. A button would have been ugly in this case :)

Comment: By the way you can move your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TextView and style the text, than you register a click listener and you are done. A link doesn't make sense as it is only useful inside web/webview. The navigation in the UI is mainly done by a button. I don't know why you don't wanna use a button, but a button is meant to be the "link" in the ui...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html). Here is a [good page on how to use Linkification in the UI](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html).

Comment: Interesting...but in my case I will just style my TextView element and associate an action to it because I just want to apply this for a single word (which is not a link or an email and hasn't a common pattern). But I didn't know the existence of Linkify and it will be useful as well! Thanks!

Comment: Right, I think the Custom Linkify section on that second page can get you what you want.